# Int placeholder on flutter localizations

Tags: flutter, localization, integer, intl, flutter-localizations

I'm trying to add a text entry to "arb" file with an int placeholder but without success as I'm getting the follow error:

```
Number format null for the times placeholder does not have a corresponding NumberFormat constructor.
Check the intl library's NumberFormat class constructors for allowed number formats.
Generating synthetic localizations package has failed.
```

The entry is the follow:

```
  "increment_message": "You have pushed the button this many times: {times}",
  "@increment_message": {
    "placeholders": {
      "times": {
        "type": "int",
        "example": "123"
      }
    }
  }
```

I know everything else is properly set because changing the placeholder to String things work:

```
  "increment_message": "You have pushed the button this many times: {times}",
  "@increment_message": {
    "placeholders": {
      "times": {
        "type": "String",
        "example": "123"
      }
    }
  }
```

[image: running app]

The complete code if you want to run is hosted on github here:

[Working using String](https://github.com/ademar111190/stack-overflow-question-arb-int)

[Failing int branch](https://github.com/ademar111190/stack-overflow-question-arb-int/tree/failing-int)

So my question is, how to use integer placeholder on arb file, it seems something related to `NumberFormat` but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

Add the format property should resolve this problem.

```
 "increment_message": "You have pushed the button this many times: {times}",
  "@increment_message": {
    "placeholders": {
      "times": {
        "type": "int",
        "format": "decimalPattern",
        "example": "123"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have launched your repo (String and int branches) and everything works fine. Did you try `flutter clean` ?

Comment: Intriguing, yes I did try to clean, I'm wondering which flutter version you are using.

Comment: Oh dear, that is it, I was running on `Flutter 2.2.3` and `Dart 2.13.4`, updating to `Flutter 2.5.2` and `Dart 2.14.3` it is working for me too, thank you for reporting it.